# Is there a method in iOS that can reload the current View?

Tags: ios, view, refresh, reload

My problem is:

I have a view to show some comments. When the view showed first time, every subview will adjust there position or hide status according to comments' count or other terms.

Also, users can post a comment at the same view, so after the comment committed, every subview should adjust there position or status according to the new comments' total count.

I can configure all the subviews that needs to change position after post connection.But that's a lot of work to do and very easy to make mistake.

However, if I can let the view reload it self(more or less like call `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` again,but reset every view), and just run the method in `viewDidLoad`, that will be much easier to refresh the comments.

So I don't know if there's a method that can reset all the subviews to origin position.
I have tried the `[self setNeedsLayout]` and `[self setNeedsDisplay]` method but won't work;

Is there a method in IOS that can reload the current View?

[image]

Comment: setNeedsLayout is used when you override drawrect method for custom drawing. setNeedsLayout should have worked.. Could you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

There is now way to update data in your subviews automatically "reloading" your view. You can update all subviews by assigning new values to them manually (via IBOutlets), distinguishing subviews by their **tags**, but that is not really good practice.

The much better approach to make a view with comments is to use custom view based on `UITableView` with individual cells representing comments.

For example, check how it is done in this class - http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/

Comment: This is a correct answer but distinguishing subviews by tags is a poor design. It's simpler to write, but harder to mantain. Tags should have never been added to views.

Comment: @Sulthan imaging you have a tableview cell with 5 subviews on it. And you need to update your, for example, 100 cells with 5 subviews each. How can you do it without using tags for these 5 subviews?

Comment: Custom cells view the subviews as properties. To access cells, you just get `visibleCells`. Even better, the cell can have a method that will receive new data an update its contents internally.

Comment: We are talking about different things I guess. Because as far as I understood you now, using properties for cell's subviews is bad design.

Comment: It's possible we don't understand ourselves well. To simplify - using tags is almost everytime bad design. I remember only one use case when it made sense.

Comment: Thank you guys, but that's not what I mean.My view more like a store info page but with the latest comment at the bottom. So I don't need a UItableview to show all the comments but I do need to update the newest comment if a user post a new comment and it's happened to be the only comment. So I need to unhide the subview that shows the latest comment and position of the uitextview for input which below the latest comment view and whose position may change according to if there is a comment.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of that view? :)

Comment: Check the screenshot I took. the view in the red rectangle is the comment part that will change.Ignore the Chinese characters please :) http://i.imgur.com/tlDIxej.png

Comment: Is that `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` in red rectangle?

Comment: No, just use some UILabel,UIImageView and UITextView and some UIView.